# Django Ignoring Remote MYSQL connection details

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework application working as expected with a local MySQL Database however, when I attempt to connect to a remote MySQL server I keep getting the following error:

**Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost**

Note the **@ localhost**, this is odd as I'm specifying a **REMOTE MySQL Host**. In my settings.py I have the following database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {}
DATABASES['user'] = {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
           'NAME': os.environ['DATABASE_NAME'],
           'USER': os.environ['DATABASE_USERNAME'],
           'PASSWORD': os.environ['DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
           'HOST:': os.environ['DATABASE_HOST'],  # this is a remote host!
           'PORT': os.environ['DATABASE_PORT'],
           
       }
```

As you can see I'm populating the parameters via explicit environment variable values. The **HOST** argument points to **db4free.net** (I have a test database located there). Thus I'm not sure why Django continues to attempt to connect to a database on localhost.

Comment: your database is setup to not to accept `my_user` login `not` from `localhost`, you need to create an user properly - for example `'my_user'@'%'`

Comment: Thanks for your response. The database is actually hosted at remote host: db4free.net and I've verified I can connect to it from both the command line: (mysql -u USER -p'PASS' -h db4free.net -P 3306 -D DATABASE_NAME)  I can also connect to if from Mysql Workbench.

Comment: @FlashThunder any other ideas what could be wrong. Its like Django is completely ignoring the remote MySQL parameters for some reason.

Comment: do you have local database set up? if not, it's not a reason

Comment: Yes I do have a local database, as I said in the question, connection to that database works as expected. The issue arrises when I attempt to connect a MySQL database running on a REMOTE host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. I've elected to post what I did to resolve the error in the hope that it may serve as some assistance to others that encounter this issue and indeed stumble across this post in an attempt to realise a prompt resolution:

So, in a nutshell, it would seem that there was some issue with the default Django MySQL driver that was, in turn, preventing remote connections from being established. To resolve this I (pip) installed this tool: https://github.com/jacobian/dj-database-url which acts as a wrapper around various database drivers. I then proceeded to import the utility to my settings.py and updated the DATABASE variable assignment to read as follows:

```
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default='mysql://'+os.environ['DATABASE_USERNAME']+':'+os.environ['DATABASE_PASSWORD']+'@'+os.environ['DATABASE_HOST']+':'+os.environ['DATABASE_PORT']+'/'+os.environ['DATABASE_NAME'])
```

notice the use of
**dj_database_url.config** in place of the direct dictionary based assignment prior. After making this change, both local and remote database connections were able to be successfully established.